# How can I make view blurry in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view, androidx

I want make this behavior for the list items background so that any thing under the view blurred :(https://s2.gifyu.com/images/61_1.iphone_x_copy_2.png)

I try coil BlurTransformation() but didn't work and this is what I archive with coil:(https://s2.gifyu.com/images/WhatsApp-Image-2021-02-20-at-13.16.51.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party libraries to achieve this.

This one is a good library [BlurView](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView)